# How to ignore "IndexError: list index out of range" on SQL Execute Insert statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I am working with Python 2.7 to extract data from a JSON API and push it into a SQL-Server table.
I am having trouble with inserting data into the database where some of the entries returned from the JSON response are missing a section of the dictionary. IE, "CustomFields": 90% of the entries have information, however 10% don't therefore I get an index error
eg

```
"CustomFields":[
],
```

vs

```
"CustomFields":[
{
"Type":"foo",
"Name":"foo",
"Value":"foo"
},
{
"Type":"foo",
"Name":"foo",
"Value":"foo"
},
{
"Type":"foo",
"Name":"foo",
"Value":"foo"
},
```

What would I change so that if I get a missing index, replace those with 'NULL' entries into the database.

```
response = '*API URL*'
json_response = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(response).read())

conn = pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=*Address*;Database=*DataBase*;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
conn.autocommit = False
c = conn.cursor()

c.executemany("INSERT INTO phil_targetproccess (ResourceType, Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate, TimeSpent, CreateDate, ModifyDate, LastStateChangeDate, ProjectName, EntityStateName, RequestTypeName, AssignedTeamMember#1, Area, SubArea, BusinessTeam) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" ,
             [(x['ResourceType'],
               x['Id'],
               x['Name'],
               (parse_date(x['StartDate'])),
               (parse_date(x['EndDate'])),
               x['TimeSpent'],
               (parse_date(x['CreateDate'])),
               (parse_date(x['ModifyDate'])),
               (parse_date(x['LastStateChangeDate'])),
               x['Project']['Name'],
               x['EntityState']['Name'],
               x['RequestType']['Name'],
               y['GeneralUser']['FirstName']+' '+y['GeneralUser']['LastName'],
               x['CustomFields'][0]['Value'],
               x['CustomFields'][1]['Value'],
               x['CustomFields'][2]['Value'])
               for x in json_response['Items']
                  for y in x['Assignments']['Items']])
```

Many thanks.

Comment: try `x.get('StartDate')` instead of `x['StartDate']`. You can specify a fallback value as the second argument to .get, by default it is None.

Comment: @bananafish for x in json_response['Items']
                  for y in x['Assignments']['Items']

It is not field defining values that are causing the issues, it is the for loop that is at the end. If I use a .get for the 'for y in ...''' I still get list index out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is here

```
 x['CustomFields'][0]['Value'],
 x['CustomFields'][1]['Value'],
 x['CustomFields'][2]['Value']
```

When CustomFields has no elements

Try

```
 x['CustomFields'][0]['Value'] if len(x['CustomFields']) > 0 else '',
 x['CustomFields'][1]['Value'] if len(x['CustomFields']) > 1 else '',
 x['CustomFields'][2]['Value'] if len(x['CustomFields']) > 2 else '',
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, that worked perfect! Now the final problem to solve, is that in the loop of "for y in x['Assignments']['Items']" If there are no keys under ['Assignments']['Items'] then a record will not be inserted into the database as it will ignore it.

Comment: What's the behavior you expect? What do you want to insert if there are no items?

Comment: I expect that a null entry will be added if no value is provided

Comment: I meant to say that all except 'GeneralUser' are retrieved from Items (x). For example, if there're no items, what are you inserting in the "ResourceType" and "ID"?

Comment: The other fields are auto generated and cannot be blank, but I will put in a statement to make it null if input is null. For now just trying to look into the "for y in x['Assignments']['Items']" so that, if that for loop is None, it will insert a null. Currently if there are no names assigned under that dict, it will just skip that record completely.

Comment: OK try this for the last line "for y in x...." here :                      for y in x['Assignments']['Items'] + ([{'GeneralUser': {'FirstName': 'N/A', 'LastName': 'N/A'}} ] if len(x['Assignments']['Items']) == 0 else [])  ])

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much!! One final hurdle, I have a columns, AssignedTeamMember#1 and AssignedTeamMember#2 (generaluser 1 and 2). Sometimes there are two users under ['Assignments']['Items']. If there are two, it enters a new row with the other first and last name, I would like the second name to be stored in a teammembertwo column on the row. If there is no second user, the field will be null. Basially I would like one record per ID, if there is a second user it will put it in the AssignedTeamMember#2 column

Comment: Then, you need to remove the second loop on y, The last line. And then, you use the same technique you used for CustomField:    (x['Assignments']['Items'][0]['FirstName']+' '+x['Assignments']['Items'][0]['LastName']) if len(x['Assignments']['Items']) > 0 else None          and another similar statement for AssignedUser#2 with index: 1 and condition > 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use get method to check whether that `value in CustomFields`

is available if so check the length of the list and then get the value of the dictionary in that list using the same get method.

For example:

```
customfield_value = (x['CustomFields'][0]).get("Value",None) if len(x['CustomFields'])>0 else None
```

This will return None if the value is not present in the index 0. you can follow the same for getting values from other 2 indices. If you didn't understand please comment it 'll explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Final Script. Thanks for the help!

```
   c.executemany("INSERT INTO phil_targetproccess (ResourceType, Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate, TimeSpent, CreateDate, "
          "ModifyDate, LastStateChangeDate, ProjectName, EntityStateName, RequestTypeName, AssignedTeamMember1, "
          "AssignedTeamMember2, AssignedTeamMember3, AssignedTeamMember4, Area, SubArea, BusinessTeam) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
          [(x['ResourceType'],
            x['Id'],
            x['Name'],
            (parse_date(x['StartDate'])),
            (parse_date(x['EndDate'])),
            x['TimeSpent'],
            (parse_date(x['CreateDate'])),
            (parse_date(x['ModifyDate'])),
            (parse_date(x['LastStateChangeDate'])),
            x['Project']['Name'],
            x['EntityState']['Name'],
            x['RequestType']['Name'],
            x['Assignments']['Items'][0]['GeneralUser']['FirstName'] + ' ' + x['Assignments']['Items'][0]['GeneralUser']['LastName'] if len(x['Assignments']['Items']) > 0 else None,
            x['Assignments']['Items'][1]['GeneralUser']['FirstName'] + ' ' + x['Assignments']['Items'][1]['GeneralUser']['LastName'] if len(x['Assignments']['Items']) > 1 else None,
            x['Assignments']['Items'][2]['GeneralUser']['FirstName'] + ' ' + x['Assignments']['Items'][2]['GeneralUser']['LastName'] if len(x['Assignments']['Items']) > 2 else None,
            x['Assignments']['Items'][3]['GeneralUser']['FirstName'] + ' ' + x['Assignments']['Items'][3]['GeneralUser']['LastName'] if len(x['Assignments']['Items']) > 3 else None,
            x['CustomFields'][0]['Value'] if len(x['CustomFields']) > 0 else '',
            x['CustomFields'][1]['Value'] if len(x['CustomFields']) > 1 else '',
            x['CustomFields'][2]['Value'] if len(x['CustomFields']) > 2 else '')
           for x in json_response['Items']])
```